# Error: Unknown property 'consolewrap.id' in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, wrapper-class

Can you please me to identify what is wrong in the below code :

**VF page :**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="relevant">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock id="block" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Recommended Resolution" id="cases" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!consolewrapperlist}" var="acc" width="100%">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                        <input type="radio" name="<strong>selectRadio</strong>" id="radio">
                        <br/>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!getSelected}" status="buttonStatus" reRender="cntblock">
                            <apex:param name="accid" value="{!acc.id}" />
                        </apex:actionSupport>
                        </input>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:commandLink value="{!acc.Name}" /> </apex:column>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class relevant {
public List<consolewrap> ConsoleWrapperList{get;set;}
 public string selectedAccountId{get; set;}
public relevant(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    getperformcallout();
 }
    public List<consolewrap> getperformcallout(){

ConsoleWrapperList = new List<consolewrap>();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

Http http = new Http();

req.setEndpoint('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parthiban019/samplejson/master/student.json');

req.setMethod('GET');
system.debug('req '+req);

res = http.send(req);
system.debug('res'+res);
system.debug('resbody'+res.getbody());
if(res.getstatusCode() == 200 && res.getbody() != null){

ConsoleWrapperList=(List<consolewrap>)json.deserialize(res.getbody(),List<consolewrap>.class);

}

return consolewrapperlist;

}
public PageReference getSelected()
    {
        System.debug('Entered account selection block');
        selectedAccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accid');
       system.debug(selectedAccountId );
        return null;
    }

}
```

**ConsoleWrap :**

```
public class consolewrap {

public String Name{get;set;}

public String AccNumber{get;set;}

public String Source{get;set;}

public String Site{get;set;}

public String Email{get;set;}

}
```

Comment: `consolewrap.id` is not being used in the page you pasted. Is it the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below statement your trying access  **acc** is of type consolewrap Class.

> `<apex:param name="accid" value="{!acc.id}" />`

In **consolewrap** class you don't have any property named with **id**.

I guess you misplace **id** instead of **AccNumber**

Below code make sense according to your wrapper class

> `<apex:param name="accid" value="{!acc.AccNumber}" />`

Comment: welcome........

Answer (score -1):

try to check whether your response is deserialized with ID.

you can do a JSON2Apex for your `res.getbody()` and check the class and its respective instance variables. Once you check that, include those variables mentioned in the JSON2Apex in your wrapper.

You can convert your `res.getBody()` json String to APEX [here](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/)